# Hacer cast con <number> no cambia el tipo de dato

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

estoy aprendiendo javascript y Angular, 
Por que al momento de ver el tipo de dato de esta variable aun especificando el tipo de dato aun me sigue saliendo como *string* siendo un *number*

```
this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe( params => {
  const idx: number = (<number>params['id']);
  console.log('por que string??? ' + typeof idx);
  this.category = this._categoryService.getCategory( idx );
});
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta utilizando el metodo `parseInt()` para convertir de `string` a `number`:

```
  const idx: number = parseInt(params['id']);
  console.log('por que string??? ' + typeof idx);
  this.category = this._categoryService.getCategory( idx );
```

A `<Type>` se le llama [`Type Assertation`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions). Segun la documentacion:

> Las aserciones de tipo son una forma de decirle al compilador "créeme,
>   sé lo que estoy haciendo". Una aserción de tipo es como un tipo de
>   conversión en otros idiomas, pero no realiza ninguna verificación
>   especial o reestructuración de datos. No tiene impacto en tiempo de
>   ejecución, y el compilador lo usa exclusivamente. TypeScript asume que
>   usted, el programador, ha realizado los controles especiales que
>   necesita

Lo que significa que no necesariamente lo casteara, sino que solo proveera mas informacion sobre el tipo a castear.

Comment: gracias, tienes razón.